# Azure backup, will connection string in app settings cause issues with existing app?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

We've upgraded our app service to S1 and want to setup automated backups. This is a .net core app with a SQL database. For the database portion, I get the following:

> No supported connection strings of type SQL Database or MySQL found configured in app.

I've adopted this project built by a previous developer and just now getting my feet wet. I understand that I can add connection strings in the app settings, but I'm concerned that it'll break the app.

For example, right now the connection string is set in the code itself, in `appsettings.json`

```
{
"Data": {
        "ConnectionStrings": {
            "ConnectionString":"Server=****;Initial Catalog=*****;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=*****;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
            //"ConnectionString":"Server=****;Initial Catalog=*****;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=*****;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"

        }
},
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
}
```

The way the other developer had it setup is the staging connection string is commented out when publishing to production, and swapped in the `appsettings.json` when published to staging. There's also another one in there that isn't in the example above for just `localhost` development.

This connection string is utilized in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString"]));


    }
```

Now this might be a silly question, but if within the app in Azure settings, if I add a connection string there to leverage the automated backups, am I going to break anything? I'm referring to selecting the app, clicking on Configure App Settings, and adding a connection string.

I'm not using slots at the moment either. So my goal is for now (as I learn more about the app that I didn't develop and learn how to use Azure) is to:

1. Setup the automated backups for the app and the SQL database
2. Not affect the app itself at runtime.

Silly as it may seem, I'm new to this environment and just a little paranoid. My gut tells me that the code will execute and stay the same, but when deploying I'm not sure if Azure does something behind the scenes that will cause this to blow up in my face.

Answer (score 2):

> No supported connection strings of type SQL Database or MySQL found configured in app.

To connect to a database, its connection string must exist in the `Connection strings` section of `Application Settings` page for your app on azure portal.
[image]
So, I suggest that you could go to portal to check the configuration whether connection string value is correct or available. The correct connection string format list at the following [site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

For more details, you could refer to [how application settings and connections work](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/).

The final and most important thing to keep in mind is that the **Azure Backup feature caches the connection string**. Any changes made to the connection after setting up your backup, will not be reflected.

If you **make changes** to the connection string, you will have to hit the `reset` button in the backup blade and **setup the backup again**. This will ensure the new connection string is pulled in.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but the connection string is valid yet still will not show in the list when trying to setup the backups. It's the same connection string used in my app itself.

Comment: I'm having the same problem too. I've tried a couple of formats starting with Server= and Data Source= based on the microsoft docs. No help.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, luckily I had a working one to draw from on another web app, **tcp:** and **,1433** is what fixed it for me and it started showing up:

```
"name": "NameHere",
"value": "Data Source=tcp:sqlservername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=sa;Password=password",
"type": "SQLAzure",
"slotSetting": true
```